# How to setState and immiediately invoke it within the same function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a function that simultaneously sets state AND assigns it to an object.. I'm specifically talking about `setValue` and `after: value`

```
    const handleAddToHistory = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    setValue((parseFloat(Object.values(data))*fromTo).toFixed(2))
    
    setHistory([ ... history , {
      date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
      before: fromTo,
      after: value,
    }])
  }
```

However, on the first run "value" is empty. It forces me to click the button again, and only then it shows all the data properly.

How can I setState and immiediately invoke it ? Should I do some sort of Time Interval on setHistory to wait until setValue is actually set?

Comment: Why not do `let newValue = (parseFloat(Object.values(data))*fromTo).toFixed(2)`, and then use `newValue` in `setState()` and `setHistory()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set state in React, it's asynchronous, since it triggers a re-render. Therefore, you use `useEffect` to handle anything that needs to happen when `value` changes:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      setHistory([ ... history , {
          date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
          before: fromTo,
          after: value,
       }])
    }, [value])
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense - thank you.. i never thought of tackling it this way

Answer (score 1):

Any reason to not do this?

```
    const handleAddToHistory = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const valueToSave = (parseFloat(Object.values(data))*fromTo).toFixed(2);
    setValue(valueToSave)
    
    setHistory([ ... history , {
      date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
      before: fromTo,
      after: valueToSave,
    }])
  }
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you can use a `useEffect` hook:

```
  const handleAddToHistory = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    setValue(parseFloat(Object.values(data))*fromTo).toFixed(2))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setHistory([ ... history , {
      date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
      before: fromTo,
      after: value,
    }]);
  }, [value]);
```